# gdb throws error when I include openssl FIPS libraries during prelaunch of the app. Linking is fine

Tags: ios, openssl, xcode4.3, fips

Editing this question as the problem is now different.

I got rid of the linking problem by building it for the right platform ( armv7).
Now , I am stuck into another issue which doesnt let me launch my app. Here is the output of my test app which basically checks whether FIPS mode is enabled or not:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Oct 17 16:52:01 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".
Setting environment variable "MallocStackLogging" to null value.
tty /dev/ttys003
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-22227-108
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 1
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 2
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 3
openssFIPSTest(235) malloc: recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder
openssFIPSTest(235) malloc: stack logs being written into /private/var/mobile/Applications/CBBB042A-B015-48B3-8CB4-8539EC8FD406/tmp/stack-logs.235.openssFIPSTest.index
openssFIPSTest(235) malloc: Please issue: cp /private/var/mobile/Applications/CBBB042A-B015-48B3-8CB4-8539EC8FD406/tmp/stack-logs.235.openssFIPSTest.jsOD6R.link /tmp/
89a6797b8847c7f20ce1ca972858d3a7e2d97e4d
```

It doesnt even get till the very first method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions.
```

There is some error in the pre-launch itself. I have restarted mac book , ipad and xcode multiple times but no luck.

Any clue whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

You have built your static library on a PC/Mac for x86, and are attempting to link it with an iOS binary which is armv6/armv7.

You need to build a multi-arch static library (i386/armv6/armv7) if you want to run your app on the simulator and all iDevices.

Comment: Thank you Karthik. I realized it last week. I built it now for armv7 and I am able to link it.